# Disabling/ Enabling javascript based on viewport width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a navigation bar which requires javascript at 400px but below 400px I have no need for it.

As the page is loaded larger than 400px then resized below that the javascript remains which results in an undesired effect. (The same goes for loading the page smaller than 400px then resizing it to be larger than). https://jsfiddle.net/abp1rwhp/4/

I am using

```
if(screen.width < 400)
```

which as I explained does the job until the user resizes the window. Does anyone know of a way I could fix my issue?

Comment: Have you tried enabling/disabling (or showing/hiding) the whole nav-bar from an `onresize` handler?

Comment: [screen.width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width) is the size of the *screen*, it is constant and doesn't change when the browser is resized. (I'm not sure but on mobile it might change if the phone orientation is rotated, but on the desktop it will be constant unless the user changes their screen resolution.) [window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) is probably what you will want to use to get the width of the  content area inside the window.

Comment: @nnnnnn no I haven't my knowledge on javacript is terribly low. Will have to research what an onresize handler is.

Comment: @UselessCode Yes I'm talking about the user changing their screen size after initially loading the page (through resizing the window). This may be rare but if it happens it breaks my navigation bar and the content below it so a fix needs to be made.

Comment: You're better off doing this with CSS. Doing this with JS listening to the `resize` event will have impact on performance.

Comment: @littlepootis Is there a way to disable/enable javascript through media queries?

Comment: No, there isn't. You *cannot* disable JavaScript.

Comment: You are not disabling JavaScript, you're trying to show/hide a navigation menu based on viewport width which is what CSS Media Queries are for.

Comment: I see what you mean. I've implemented this into my project, it now works if you load it greater than 980px then resize it smaller than but not the other way round. this may work, I don't see many people loading the page smaller than 980px then resizing it greater than. (By the way in my project it's 980px I did 400px for my example).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick where .nav is the css selector for your nav

```
var showHideMyNav = function () {
    if (window.outerWidth < 400) {
        var nav = document.querySelector(".nav");
        nav.style.visibility = "hidden"; // $('#nav-bar').hide();
    } else {
        nav.style.visibility = "visible"; // $('#nav-bar').show();
    }
};
window.addEventListener('resize', showHideMyNav); // $(window).on("resize, ...);
```

Comment: on first line `showHideMyNav()` should be `showHideMyNav`, because your function does not return anything and thus passing undefined to an event listener

Comment: True, typo, but you see the idea :)

Comment: For this solution to work do I need to basically build two separate navigation bars? Not against the idea just curious. Because as I applied that to my script it hid the bar as I resized to either greater or less than 400px.

Comment: no just one, on your example, please see https://jsfiddle.net/abp1rwhp/12/
I didn't use jQuery here just good old JS and I changed the number to 700 just for my own test (my window doesn't get smaller) but should work as you expect. The only thing I changed is moved your nav outside the function to keep it's value somewhere and it doesn't run out of scope

Comment: Thanks for the help, by the look of it your example is working the same way as my initial one. You may not be able to see the problem I'm having if you can't resize your browser to less than 400 (or 700). In my example there are two different states for the nav bar based on screen width. I'll play around with what you have given me and see what I can do from there. thanks :)